# Can someone describe what these connections are and why there are so many of them?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and when I start my laptop I see lots of connections related to chrome like below. Can someone tell me what this is all about?

```
$ netstat -plant | grep chrome
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:54466      192.0.73.2:443          ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:58838      34.96.110.71:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:50454      140.82.113.25:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:41750      142.250.4.157:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:54382      104.16.124.127:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:42746      172.217.160.170:443     ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:51864      142.250.67.141:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:55546      13.227.138.83:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:52370      13.227.138.119:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0   1233 192.168.1.81:40696      52.35.83.204:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:51746      142.250.67.226:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:42440      172.217.166.67:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:52772      151.101.8.157:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56328      3.232.57.107:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:44342      142.250.67.142:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:51018      104.16.117.145:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:42326      13.227.138.69:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:48016      104.26.4.74:443         ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56362      3.232.57.107:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:47646      151.101.0.133:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:47506      151.101.0.133:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:34812      172.217.174.226:443     ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:50238      172.217.160.206:443     ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:44738      13.227.138.110:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56358      3.232.57.107:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:43768      216.58.199.142:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:34806      172.217.160.194:443     ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:37662      52.215.192.131:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:55364      13.227.250.43:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:36278      3.223.37.94:443         ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56322      3.232.57.107:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:59232      172.217.167.163:443     ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:51354      35.186.205.6:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:47514      151.101.0.133:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:51294      142.250.67.232:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:35162      151.101.2.217:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:43772      216.58.199.142:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56474      142.250.76.174:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:35146      142.250.67.202:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:42254      216.58.199.176:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:53304      172.217.194.188:5228    ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:60310      13.248.151.210:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:46166      142.250.67.131:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:37446      13.227.250.175:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56360      3.232.57.107:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56356      3.232.57.107:443        ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:42412      172.217.166.67:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56168      13.227.136.78:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:40284      216.58.203.163:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:54416      192.0.73.2:443          ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:57034      172.217.174.78:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:43394      13.227.138.51:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:33822      74.125.24.155:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:44402      172.217.160.174:443     ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:56188      172.217.167.170:443     ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:38624      172.217.174.228:443     ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:35482      172.67.222.232:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:44376      142.250.67.142:443      ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:45552      35.190.88.7:443         ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.81:44536      172.64.139.36:443       ESTABLISHED 4232/chrome --type=
```

Result of `sudo lsof -i | grep chrome`

```
chrome    3555         user  275u  IPv4  61965      0t0  UDP 224.0.0.251:mdns 
chrome    3823         user   23u  IPv4  88429      0t0  TCP laptop-name:59162->104.19.161.127:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   32u  IPv4  88795      0t0  TCP laptop-name:43236->bom07s25-in-f4.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   33u  IPv4  92536      0t0  TCP laptop-name:47546->ec2-3-94-218-138.compute-1.amazonaws.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   35u  IPv4  91725      0t0  TCP laptop-name:43304->ec2-3-94-218-138.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   36u  IPv4  88810      0t0  TCP laptop-name:48456->151.101.193.69:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   38u  IPv4  91660      0t0  TCP laptop-name:47548->ec2-3-94-218-138.compute-1.amazonaws.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   39u  IPv4  94381      0t0  TCP laptop-name:49682->server-13-227-178-25.bom51.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   41u  IPv4  94377      0t0  TCP laptop-name:42654->bom05s12-in-f14.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   43u  IPv4  89899      0t0  TCP laptop-name:46170->server-13-227-234-9.bom51.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   44u  IPv4  91676      0t0  TCP laptop-name:45620->bom12s05-in-f3.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   45u  IPv4  82065      0t0  TCP laptop-name:42760->bom07s25-in-f4.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   48u  IPv4  90459      0t0  TCP laptop-name:48646->192.0.73.2:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   50u  IPv4  88311      0t0  TCP laptop-name:57114->104.18.89.237:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   51u  IPv4  87241      0t0  TCP laptop-name:36506->bom12s08-in-f10.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   55u  IPv4  89648      0t0  TCP laptop-name:44602->151.101.10.208:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   56u  IPv4  91483      0t0  TCP laptop-name:34846->kul01s09-in-f66.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   57u  IPv4  89330      0t0  TCP laptop-name:57118->104.18.89.237:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   59u  IPv4  91502      0t0  TCP laptop-name:43086->103.229.10.236:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   61u  IPv4  91487      0t0  TCP laptop-name:59402->a23-9-208-202.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   62u  IPv4  84851      0t0  TCP laptop-name:42436->bom07s12-in-f2.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   64u  IPv4  56265      0t0  TCP laptop-name:43532->bom07s01-in-f14.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   65u  IPv4  91540      0t0  TCP laptop-name:48942->stackoverflow.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   70u  IPv4  63486      0t0  TCP laptop-name:45332->bom12s09-in-f10.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   71u  IPv4  91503      0t0  TCP laptop-name:56398->142.250.4.157:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   72u  IPv4  68967      0t0  TCP laptop-name:55764->hkg12s09-in-f14.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   76u  IPv4  85936      0t0  TCP laptop-name:49192->104.16.54.15:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   77u  IPv4  80706      0t0  TCP laptop-name:58790->bom07s16-in-f2.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   81u  IPv4  63713      0t0  TCP laptop-name:54694->74.125.24.188:5228 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   83u  IPv4  62959      0t0  TCP laptop-name:50596->104.18.61.8:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   89u  IPv4  89909      0t0  TCP laptop-name:34580->104.16.0.35:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   91u  IPv4  86649      0t0  TCP laptop-name:47576->lb-140-82-112-25-iad.github.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user   96u  IPv4  88488      0t0  TCP laptop-name:56786->104.17.53.70:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  105u  IPv4  88441      0t0  TCP laptop-name:50804->104.20.124.103:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  108u  IPv4  86791      0t0  TCP laptop-name:36518->104.18.114.44:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  109u  IPv4  88486      0t0  TCP laptop-name:34852->104.16.94.80:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  114u  IPv4  89569      0t0  TCP laptop-name:54894->104.18.28.147:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  117u  IPv4  89574      0t0  TCP laptop-name:43382->104.17.208.240:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  126u  IPv4  87650      0t0  TCP laptop-name:42094->ec2-35-170-255-106.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  128u  IPv4  86837      0t0  TCP laptop-name:60586->151.101.1.2:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  131u  IPv4  86807      0t0  TCP laptop-name:44440->151.101.10.208:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  132u  IPv4  86808      0t0  TCP laptop-name:44442->151.101.10.208:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  134u  IPv4  87624      0t0  TCP laptop-name:59202->104.19.161.127:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  135u  IPv4  89585      0t0  TCP laptop-name:35540->104.19.147.8:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  136u  IPv4  62168      0t0  TCP laptop-name:48196->edge-star-shv-02-sin6.facebook.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  140u  IPv4  86922      0t0  TCP laptop-name:40776->104.18.101.194:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  141u  IPv4  86814      0t0  TCP laptop-name:40906->104.16.95.80:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  157u  IPv4  87664      0t0  TCP laptop-name:55962->151.101.1.44:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  162u  IPv4  87668      0t0  TCP laptop-name:35534->104.19.147.8:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  175u  IPv4  86901      0t0  TCP laptop-name:32800->104.16.18.94:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    3823         user  207u  IPv4  88587      0t0  TCP laptop-name:43528->104.17.208.240:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: Is this seen immediately after boot or just after Chrome opens? Do you leave a lot of tabs open that need to be restored when opening the browser?

Comment: They're all connections to the `https` port on the various systems. Find out which process has opened the connections with `sudo lsof -i` on a command line.

Comment: I see these after I open chrome. I have not opened a lot of tabs. There are 6 tabs opened. 

chrome is the process that has opened the connections, looks like all are either ec2, google, etc

Is this normal to open so many connections when only 6 tabs are opened?